# Send google analytics event when time on page goes over 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have a client with a 1 page website. He'd like to track people who have spent more than 30 seconds on the page as a goal completion.

I was thinking I could use javascript to count the time on page and when it goes over 30 seconds trigger the an analytics event.

I'm fairly unfamiliar with javascript but I did come across this simple counter which counts up from 0 on page load.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var works = document.getElementById("works");
    var totalSeconds = 0;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);

    function setTime()
    {
        ++totalSeconds;
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
    }

    function pad(val)
    {
        var valString = val + "";
        if(valString.length < 2)
        {
            return "0" + valString;
        }
        else
        {
            return valString;
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Is there some way I have have it send the event below when the "totalSeconds" hits 30?

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'time on page', 'over 30 seconds');"
```

thanks!

Comment: Does the page deploy GTM? Potentially this could be done very easily with the gtm.timer event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it up in GA in the admin view settings under goals.

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't know about this setting. Will do it this way.

Comment: Just a thought, will this work even if the visitors bounce? I know GA measures time on page by comparing time stamps between one page and the next. if there is no next page will it still work?

Comment: From my understanding, the number of pages shouldn't matter, according to google the duration uses the session time so if you have one page and the user exits your site after 30seconds, it should still register as a goal conversion. 
[Analytics docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en)

Comment: This will not work for a 1 page site - Jamie you are correct about timestamps. Time on page only works if the user goes to another page on your site OR triggers an event (i.e. does something that sends a message to your Analytics account.) For a 1 page site you could try this: https://blog.littledata.io/2016/11/13/accurate-tracking-of-time-on-site/

Answer (score 0):

What about doing :

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        ga('send', 'event', 'time on page', 'over 30 seconds');
    }, 30000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Looks good in theory. Tried adding it in to the header, if I go to the real time tracker in analytics I can see me land on the page but the event doesn't trigger after 30 seconds.  Any ideas?